# Get / Set calendar events on iCal (programmatically)

Tags: objective-c, macos, icalendar, calendar-store

is there any objective C API or object that can give me access to the iCal and its events?
I need to read the calendar events for a given date and optionally set a new event.

The code is either plain C or objective C (in the GUI version of the program). I'm using xcode on a mac os 10.6.

Sample code is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

As of 10.8 (Mountain Lion), [Calendar Store is deprecated](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/MacOSX/WhatsNewInOSX/Articles/MacOSX10_8.html). You should now use [Event Kit](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Answer (score 1):

You might find it easier to use iCal's Apple Events scripting interface.  If you don't like the idea of using AppleScript directly, there is Apple's [Scripting Bridge](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptingBridgeConcepts/UsingScriptingBridge/UsingScriptingBridge.html) or, even better, use [Appscript](http://appscript.sourceforge.net/) for Objective-C, Ruby, or Python.  Here's one way to access and modify the events for a given day using py-appscript:

```
>>> from appscript import *
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> start_time = datetime(2009,10,26)
>>> end_time = datetime(2009,10,26,23,59,59)
>>> calendar = app('iCal').calendars['Home']
>>> for event in calendar.events[(its.start_date >= start_time).AND(its.start_date <= end_time)]():
...   event_properties = event.properties()
...   print event_properties[k.start_date], event_properties[k.summary]
... 
2009-10-26 18:40:00 <event 1>
2009-10-26 23:38:00 <event 2>
>>> event.summary.set(to='something else')
```

Comment: thank you but even tho i like Python and other scripts a lot I can't use that this time. Either C or objective C

Comment: It should be simple to translate that code to the Objective C version of Appscript.

Comment: the reason I asked in the 1st place is because I don't even know what objects or API's I need to be able to talk to the calendar store. So, translating that would be a bit difficult if I don't know what functions I need.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand correctly but, if you want to understand the iCal scripting data model, the standard way to do that - as with any OS X scriptable app - is to introspect the model using the AppleScript Editor (in /Applications/Utilites) Open Dictionary command. But in this case use the tools provided with Appscript (http://appscript.sourceforge.net/tools.html): ASDictionary translates the iCal's data model dictionary into Objective C-appscript syntax and can also automatically generate all the Objective C glue code to access that data model.

In any case, good luck.

Comment: Using Apple Events has the *big* disadvantage of needing iCal to be launched when accessing it. The Calendar Store is designed exactly to avoid doing this.

Comment: It's true iCal has to be running when using Apple Events. That may be a disadvantage depending on your application. All in all, using the Calendar Store framework is a more robust solution but, for many applications, using Apple Events is perfectly adequate, plus the approach generalizes to most other OS X scriptable applications - even if there isn't a "standalone" API alternative.

Comment: Thanks all, but PLEASE i don't want a script. I clearly wrote that I need to code this in C or objective C. I don't understand why this isn't clear.

Comment: and no, I don't want to try this. and no, I don't want to translate this. Thanks for the answer but it's not what i am looking for.